# ¿Como instalar TKinter para python?

Tags: python, tkinter

LLevo un buen rato intentandolo pero no puedo ya que trato de instalarlo con pip install TKinter y me di cuenta que TKinter no es paquete por lo tanto no puedo descargarlo como [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Si utilizas Python2 el módulo es `Tkinter` (la primera letra es mayúscula), si usas pythpn3 el modulo es `tkinter`. Creo que a solución es que ejecutes `python3 aplicacion_main.py`

Comment: ok lo voy a intentar

Answer (score 1):

1. Debes saber con qué versión de  python trabajas
2. Comandos correctos según tu sistema operativo (vi que estás trabajando en Windows)
3. Te adjunto la documentación de la librería para la isntalación en tu SO

[documentación Tk](https://tkdocs.com/tutorial/install.html)

4. Al final debes importar correctamente:

   import Tkinter as tk

   Para Python3 :

   import tkinter as tk

Espero que te sirva! :)